# How do you create a timer (preferably ten minutes) that activates redstone every time it activates in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands

Im just starting to use command blocks and im still figuring out how a lot of stuff works.

Comment: I recommend googling "Minecraft 5 minute timer", I'll write a proper answer later today.

Comment: Personally, I would use a scoreboard timer, mainly for space and ease of manipulation. Each minute is 1200 ticks, so if you run a loop that adds a score of 1 to an armor stand you can detect when a minute is up. For a ten minute timer you would execute all armor stands with that score of 120,000. I'm going to leave it at that though, it looks like Fabian is going to go more into it later.

Comment: @SpiceWeasel I totally overlooked the commands tag. Yes, scoreboards are better then. And in 1.14 scheduled functions. You can write an answer using commands, mine is only redstone, because I assumed Survival mode.

Comment: @Fabian Commands might be better, but your method is not only easier for new people AND survival compatible but he's new to commands, and in my experience ones who are new with commands like to use a lot of redstone. You're answer works well anyway, so maybe I'll not post one. ;]

Comment: Then I'll do it when I have more time. So in 2020 or so… :D

Answer (score 2):

You can make a 5 minute timer by dropping an item onto a golden or iron pressure plate and activating the output when it despawns. You can chain two of those to create a 10 minute timer.

This could look like this:

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a 10 minute timer by getting a signal out of a daylight sensor. It's not exact. but if you get a pulse when it goes above or below signal strength 7, then you have a timer that gives off a pulse after 9m56s, then after 10m04s, then 9m56s and so on.

Comment: Oops, I had the command input active in the screenshot. Whatever, won't change that now.